# Talend real time Big Data product, using Cassandra as streaming source

Tags: cassandra, talend

I trying to implement below flow in Talend real time Big data product.

Cassandra ----------> Talend RT BD -----> Google Big Query

(Real time read from cassandra tables?)

Can we have Cassandra source for real time, because in tool source object not provided for Cassandra.

[image: Talend rt bd image]

Comment: The question is not clear to me. What do you mean by "source for real time"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @tobi6 i mean Source object to build job in Talend Big data Streaming. I can't see tCassandraInput Object in tool.

Answer (score 0):

Since `tCassandraInput` *should* be part of the Talend Realtime Big Data Suite, the components could be hidden. Try this:

1. Open the project settings window, click Designer, then Palette Settings.
2. Check if the components are in the Hide side, if so, move them to the Show side. If the components have been in the Show side, but you do not sill [sic!] find them in the palette, move them to the Hide side, and move them back to Show side.

[Source](https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=29235)

Otherwise, try to search specifically `tCassandraInput` in the search component input field, which says `Find component...`.